# Using conditional formatting in excel rosters to ensure correct shift are entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

probably a simple question. but i need help :( my company is still in the dark ages rotering up to 500 staff on a "simple" excel file. Using Night, Day and Back as shifts. Unfortunately we have new staff who are entering "day" shifts directly after "night" shift.  There has to be a simple forumula that will turn the "day" shift red if this is entered?
Please help.

Comment: Can you show an example

Comment: simply shifts are entered  DAYSHIFT BACKSHIFT NIGHTSHIFT, accross the line, under the day heading.  if a person is working a night shift 10pm to 6am, they cannot work a day shift, starting at 6am the following day,.  this is causing issues as we are then understaffed and i cant discipline the staff not staying to work 16hrs! the previous comment shows me how to highlight one celll, which I can copy down the page, but not accross? ie, the below works for all in colum B and c, am I making sense?

Comment: You can select all the columns that you want to Format and use the same formula and change "day" to your data and "night" also

Comment: Leave the first day and select the following days and use the corrected formula in the answer

Comment: YASS : MANY THANKS... I finaly got it, dont know what  I was doing last night. Now, just to take it into work and "fix" all my files,

Answer (score 1):

If column B is the shift column and you are looking for "day" to format red, select the Shift Columns after the first day and use:

- Conditional Formatting,
- New Rule,
- Use a Formula to determine which cells to Format
- and write the following:

  B2 being the first cell in your column with Data

  `=AND(B2="nightshift",C2="dayshift")`
  whenever day is written after night
  And Format as you wish

Comment: hi, many thanks on the above, I need it to only turn red if for example b2 = night  and c2 = day as you cannot work a day shift after a night shift,?

Comment: I updated the formula to correspond your example